# Suppose $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ is countable for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, is $X=f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ countable?

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
The following exercise is Exercise 19 on p.39 in Exercises 2B in this book.

> Exercise 19
> Suppose $X$ is a nonempty set and $\mathcal{S}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ consisting of all subsets of $X$ that are either countable or have a countable complement in $X$. Give a characterization of the $\mathcal{S}$-measurable real-valued functions on $X$.

Now I am trying to solve Exercise 19.
And I wonder if the following proposition is true.

> Let $X$ be a set.
> Let $f$ be a mapping from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
> Suppose $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ is countable for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$.
> Then, is $X=f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ countable?

Comment: Maybe can help the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ can be covered by a countable many intervals of the form $(a,\infty)$.

Comment: @CarlosJiménez Thank you very much for your answer. $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=f^{-1}(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} (n,\infty))=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} f^{-1}((n,\infty)).$ So, $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ is countable.